# CSS keyframe animation -webkit-transform reset Chrome Bug

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, css-transforms, css-animations

I'm getting a bug using CSS keyframe animation.

When animating the `-webkit-transform` property, if I add `-webkit-animation-play-state: paused;` and then remove it, the animation quickly jumps back to the start and then resumes again.

Here is an example of this in action: http://jsfiddle.net/NAjFf/8/
It even happens when toggling the animation state with javascript: http://jsfiddle.net/NAjFf/7/

Is there a workaround for this issue?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It's a bug issue in webkit, everyone affected by it might be interested in Roman Komarov's technique of tricking WebKit into transitions on pseudos via inheritance.

Checkout the below link

[pseudos](http://kizu.ru/en/pseudos/)

:)

Comment: By now, [animating pseudo elements](http://jsfiddle.net/6AnfX/) is supported by most (if not all) major browsers, it works fine in Firefox, Chrome, IE and Opera. I'm not sure about Safari. Anyway, how is this supposed to help fixing the problem? Can you supply an example?